# ssh _from_ Linux _to_ Windows: Which editor to use on Windows machine?

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, text-editors

We have a situation where we have a SSH-server running on a Windows host which we then use an ssh client in e.g. an xterm (or another vt100 compatible client) to connect to, and then get a DOS prompt (but without any GUI at all).

Now we need to have a good editor on the Windows machine which will work out of the box in this scenario.    I do not have any experience with this, so I do not know where to start.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try [vim for windows](http://www.vim.org/download.php), its the best editor for all platforms.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i'll take that for next answers. But this is a link to the download page.

Comment: Have you validated it will work in the scenario I describe?

Comment: I have not tried it with ssh, but it work fine with a dos prompt. you should download the [Win32 console executable](ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/pc/vim74w32.zip), it has all what you need.
you may want to add it to your path.

Answer (score -1):

There is this [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/index.html) project which offers a linuxstyle command line interface to windwos. Thing is i do not know if it works with windows server. As I last used it it offered a menu point to  install vim (which is my favourite editor on Linux. It takes some time to learn to use it, but once you get the hang with it, it is a very powerful tool.) But nano and emacs is also on the [package list](https://cygwin.com/packages/) I think you should give it  a go. (nano and emacs are both a bit more intuitive to handle) =)

**Edit 18.08.14:**

Since you want to run the commands on the DOS terminal you have to remember to update the PATH variable to include the path to the \bin folder of you cygwin installation. If your ssh server has a own variable to specify where binaries are stored, be sure to update it.

Comment: The exact editor is not important as long as it works well.

Comment: I have used it on Win7 and XP and it worked fine, as fare as I was concerned. But I think nothing gets you past field testing it yourself. Something can always go wrong. But that is why i prefer to work with computers rather than humans. They a fare more convenient to debug. =)

Comment: Don't get me wrong. I just wanted to make clear that I did not have 100 users doing all sorts of crazy stuff with it. I have just used it to do some basic network administration on a multi-platform environment.

Comment: So you are actively using vim on a Windows server you reach with ssh?

Comment: No, I stated in the main post: I do not know if it works on Windows Server edition. And I do not use it anymore, since I moved all the boxes to Linux. But as I said above, I used it on Win7 and XP.

Comment: When I say server I mean it as in "Where the ssh daemon is running", not as the flavor of Windows.  If you have it running with Windows 7, I'll give it a go.